# iOS SDK SOAP parsing error : Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: ios, iphone, soap, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I am developing an iPhone app. I have to get data from .NET server. The response is in the following form.

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
{"success":1,"message":"Data Save Successfully.","returnvalue":"106"}
</string>
```

I am using NSXMLParser to parse to parse it. I want to get the json string . But the parser is giving error

```
Server was unable to process request. ---> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

How can i fix the error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My url was not right, thats why I was getting this error. I found that error and every thing is working fine with NSXMLParser. That was a silly mistake.

Comment: What's your code? I didn't get any issue with retrieving the JSON data.

Comment: In the previous comment I told that there was a typo mistake in the url, thats  why I was getting this error. After resolving that mistake the code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

The String in the respons is a JSON, So i think the `NSXMLParser` don't work with a JSON input. The parsing error is because the syntax of XML is different then from JSON.

This link will help you to read the String JSON response you get.
[how to parse json with swift2](http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/10/how-to-parse-json-with-swift-2/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Json parser will not be able to parse it.